# Why and how do params in annotate affect each other?

Tags: python, django, aggregate-functions

I've been reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/ a lot, but I'm still missing something.

Using Django 1.11, say I have the following models:

```
class School(models.Model):
    pass

class Classroom(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    busy = models.BooleanField()

class Chalkboard(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Whiteboard(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And I create a school, with a classroom, which has 2 whiteboards and 2 chalkboards:

```
s = School()
s.save()

c = Classroom(school=s, active=True, busy=False)
c.save()

Chalkboard(classroom=c).save()
Chalkboard(classroom=c).save()

Whiteboard(classroom=c).save()
Whiteboard(classroom=c).save()
Whiteboard(classroom=c).save()
```

I want a summary of how many chalkboards there are at each school that is active but not busy.

```
q = School.objects.filter(
    Q(classroom__active=True) & Q(classroom__busy=False)
).annotate(
    chalkboard_count=Count('classroom__chalkboard'),
)

q[0].chalkboard_count
2                        # as expected
```

Now I want to know about chalkboards and whiteboards.

```
q = School.objects.filter(
    Q(classroom__active=True) & Q(classroom__busy=False)
).annotate(
    chalkboard_count=Count('classroom__chalkboard'),
    whiteboard_count=Count('classroom__whiteboard'), # added this line
)

q[0].chalkboard_count
6                        # expected 2
q[0].whiteboard_count
6                        # expected 3
```

If I chain the calls to annotate, I get the same result.

```
q = School.objects.filter(
    Q(classroom__active=True) & Q(classroom__busy=False)
).annotate(
    chalkboard_count=Count('classroom__chalkboard')
).annotate(
    whiteboard_count=Count('classroom__whiteboard')
)

q[0].chalkboard_count
6                        # expected 2
q[0].whiteboard_count
6                        # expected 3
```

All the while, the counts are what I expect

```
Chalkboard.objects.count()
2
Whiteboard.objects.count()
3
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you posted:

> ### Combining multiple aggregations
>
> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong
>   results because joins are used instead of subqueries:
>   For most aggregates, there is no way to avoid this problem, however,
>   the Count aggregate has a distinct parameter that may help:

```
Book.objects.annotate(
    Count('authors', distinct=True), 
    Count('store', distinct=True)
)
```

Comment: It was right in front of me and I missed it.  Thanks!